# Filebench Error: out of shared memory when I try to set $nfiles a very big number (about 1000000)

Tags: microbenchmark

When I use filebench to test my file system, the process crashed  when I try to set $nfiles a very big number (about 1000000). And the way in the official site do not work!

Here is the solution on the official web site

Second warning informs that Filebench was not able to increase shared memory region size. You can either:
    * Run Filebench as root
    * Increase shared memory region size to 256MB (sudo echo 268435456 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space) and ignore this warning

Answer (score 2):

The shared memory region size is based on the size of the filebench_shm_t struct. If you want to run with more files, you will need to modify the struct. You can do this by modifying ipc.h before compiling. Since you want set $nfiles to a large number, I suggest changing the line:

```
#define FILEBENCH_NFILESETENTRIES       (1024 * 1024)
```

to

```
#define FILEBENCH_NFILESETENTRIES       (1024 * 1024 * 10)
```

Recompile and retest. On my RHEL6 machine, the shared memory region went from 170MB to close to 1.5GB.

HTH,
Scott